# Greek Ruins -- Previous Sites for Pagan Worship

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, rambam, travel, chutz-laaretz

I know that Maimonides states not to enter places of idol worship. That being the case, is it permissible to visit Greek ruins that where once used for a pagan religion?